# How to get all possible subsets of a set

Tags: c, arrays, subset

Can someone explain to me how to generate all subsets of a set using an algorithm which has complexity lower or equal to the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void printPowerSet(char *set, int set_size)
{
    /*set_size of power set of a set with set_size
      n is (2**n -1)*/
    unsigned int pow_set_size = pow(2, set_size);
    int counter, j;

    /*Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1*/
    for(counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < set_size; j++)
       {
          /* Check if jth bit in the counter is set
             If set then pront jth element from set */
          if(counter & (1<<j))
            printf("%c", set[j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
}

/*Driver program to test printPowerSet*/
int main()
{
    char set[] = {'a','b','c'};
    printPowerSet(set, 3);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

For example if my input is

```
3
2 3 4
```

I should get my output as

```
{2} {3} {4} {2,3} {2,4} {3,4} {2,3,4}
```

Comment: Are you asking us if it possible? Or whether we can write it for you?

Comment: Google "permutations".

Comment: For the specified input, what is you *actual* output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see that it behaves as it should? Have you tried explaining the code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Have you tried to solve it on paper first before you started programming?

Comment: Shouldn't the power set also include the empty set?

Comment: No there is no need of empty set @IanAbbott

Comment: I'am asking whether it is possible or not @Mozahler

Comment: I've tried the program already it gives the same output as i mentioned in the question.I'am asking whether there is another method for this question other than the program mentioned in my question.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I've tried but all the programs in the search are for getting the contiguous sub array.@Lundin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: the following is intended for showing the concept of generating the powerset of a set.

- starts with the empty set and add it to the powerset `sets`:
- for each element `el[i]`  of your set `el`

  - for each subset `add` already present in `sets`

    - augment `add` by pushing_back `el[i]` to it
    - push the augmented set to `sets`

Here is a proof of concept in `c++`

```
void generateSubset(vector<int>& el) {
    vector<vector<int>> sets;
    sets.push_back(vector<int>());
    for (int i = 0; i < el.size() ; i++) {
        vector<vector<int>> ssets;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < sets.size() ; j++ ) {
            vector<int> add(sets[j]);
            add.push_back(el[i]);
            ssets.push_back(add);
        }
        sets.insert(sets.end(), begin(ssets), end(ssets));
    }
    
//print the subsets
    for (int j = 0 ; j < sets.size() ; j++ ) {
        auto v = sets[j];
        for (auto a : v) {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "#subsets "<<sets.size() << endl;
}



int main() {
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    generateSubset(a);
}
```

Hope this helps understanding how to generate the powerset.